# Changing input file parameters and recursively running program - Using AWK or Shell Scripts?

Tags: shell, recursion, awk

I'm currently running a program which accepts an input file. The input file has various parameters, 3 of which I need to change, run again, etc.
The range of those 3 parameters are 15 values for one, 12 values for another and 10 for another, so I have 15*12*10 (=1800) possible input files I need to make for the program. The output filename will need to match the parameters for that run as well. Obviously creating 3375 input files by hand would be impractical, not only because it would be time consuming but the risk of human error would be great. I need help with the following:

1. Varying the parameters of my input file. I know this can be done with AWK, or perhaps using shell script. The input file is plain text (ascii)
2. recursively running the script each time a parameter is changed. Suppose my input file looks like:

   ## input file mockup

   ## Value for A

   1

   ## Value for B

   2

   ## Value for C

   4

   ## Value for D

   12

Suppose the three parameters I want to change are A, B and D. Suppose each value of A is spaced 5 units apart, and I want to run over 3 values. My possible values of A would then be {1, 6, 11}
My possible values for B are spaced 3 units apart and there are 4 values {2, 5, 8, 11}
and my Values for D are spaced 1 apart and there are two of them {12, 13}
Allowing for repeated values, the sets I would want process are:

{1, 2, 12}

{1, 5, 12}

{1, 8, 12}

{1, 11, 12}

{1, 2, 13}

{1, 5, 13}

{1, 8, 13}

{1, 11, 13}

{6, 2, 12}

{6, 5, 12}

{6, 8, 12}

{6, 11, 12}

{6, 2, 13}

{6, 5, 13}

{6, 8, 13}

{6, 11, 13}

{11, 2, 12}

{11, 5, 12}

{11, 8, 12}

{11, 11, 12}

{11, 2, 13}

{11, 5, 13}

{11, 8, 13}

{11, 11, 13}

where each place in the brackets corresponds to the values for {A, B, D}

So my two problems are essentially:
1 Make a wrapper to run the program recursively with the changed input file
2 Change the three variables so I get every combination and pass the corresponding input file to the program.

here's what I think it should look like in pseudo-code (I know this is wrong need some help):

```
A = 1
B = 2
D = 12

for B<11, 
 for A<11, 
  for D<13, 
   B+3, A+5, D++, program input file

#input file mockup
#Value for A
Some Expression for {A}
#Value for B
Some Expression for {B}
#Value for C
4
#Value for D
Some Expression for {D}

outputdirectory: mkdir Run.ABD
```

or something like this....

NOTE: I've posted this question on a different site to see if anyone else could answer it there. I am not trolling or crowd-sourcing; looking for genuine help.
Also, if anyone's interested, I'm running a co-seismic displacement model for which I need to vary the depth, length and displacement each run through. I'm assuming linear slip and uniform viscosity throughout the medium. The program is fine and ready to go I just need to figure out a way to alter my input file with variable parameters.

EDIT:

I realize my logic loop should look something like:

```
A=1
B=2
D=12
While A<11
    While B<11
        While D<13
        D++
    B+3
A+5
```

Please let me know if this is the right idea? I don't know how to store the variables so each iteration of the loop creates a new input file or input parameters.

Or maybe something like this?

```
A=1
While A<11
    B = 2
    While B<11
        D=12
        While D<13
        D++
    B+3
A+5
```

Comment: This question is nearly incomprehensible.  One specific question I have: if there are 1800 possible input files, why would you create 3375 if you created them by hand?  If the input can be generated, why bother creating input files?  Just generate the data as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I've zoned out each time I've tried to read your description as I'm getting lost in the terminology and explanations and I'm confused about you asking for a recursive solution but then showing non-recursive algorithms, but if you're saying you just want to generate a bunch of files where each contains 3 fields and the values of each field range as:

- field 1 = 1 to 11 by 5s
- field 2 = 2 to 11 by 3s
- field 3 = 12 to 13 by 1s

and store each combination in a separate file named, say "outfileN" with N being a number starting at 1, then that'd just be:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
   for (i=1;i<=11;i+=5) {
      for (j=2;j<=11;j+=3) {
         for (k=12;k<=13;k+=1) {
            print i,j,k > (outfile ++n)
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

If that doesn't do what you want, tell us in what way it fails.

Comment: Hi, the algorithm is not supposed to be recursive, but the files that it generates should be, in that they cover every possible combination of parameters. I'll give your script a try tomorrow in the morning. I took a break from this project for a few weeks to think it through a little bit more. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear to me why you want to create an input value for each set of parameters rather than simply generating the data as needed. Perhaps you are simply looking for something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=5
for (( a=1; a <= 11; a += 5 )); do
for (( b=2; b <= 11; b += 1 )); do
for (( d=12; d <= 13; d += 1 )); do
    cat << EOF |  # Pipe the data into the awk below
input file mockup
Value for A

$a
Value for B

$b
Value for C

$c
Value for D

$d
EOF
    awk 1 > output-$a-$b-$c-$d  # process with a trivial awk script
done
done
done
```

If you want to keep the input files, just redirect the cat to a file and process that file rather than using a pipe.